# AWS SSM getparameters make behavior node js sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, aws-ssm

Is there any way to make AWS SSM getparameters sync?
Requirement :
The secret key, id stored in the SSM store should be accessible on the server up.
Using Node and express in the backend as a reverse proxy, so we have a constant.js file, it stores all the API URLs, paths, etc.

***constats.js file***

```
const api1url = 'http://example.com/path1'
const api1_secretkey = 'secret_key'
..................

module.export = {api1url,api1_secretkey}
```

So we wanted to call the ssm stuff in here before setting the const variables

```
const SSM = require('aws-sdk/clients/ssm');
const ssm = new SSM();
const params = {
   Names: ['/secret_key_api_1', '/secret_key_api_2'],
   WithDecryption: true,
   };
 const parameterList = await ssm.getParameters(params).promise();
```

I understand that await cant be without async, I just wanted to convey what I am expecting, without it being an async call or whether it be in the callback of getparameters.

```
const api1url = 'http://example.com/path1'
const api1_secretkey = parameterList.Parameter[1].Value
```

But since it is an async call we are not able to wait for it,tried doing it in a separate async function and then returning the data but since the function is still async having difficulties.

Not exactly issue wrt to an async function, the async function works as expected, but I want it to be synced, the AWS  get parameter function is async. because of this I am not able to do something like const api1_secretkey = process.env.secret_key  , this value will be obtained when js file is executed line by line. but since i am waiting for the secret key to come from async func  by the time the line by line occurs const api1_secretkey = parameterList.Parameter[1].Value , the promise is still not resolved so undefined will sit. Even if i make a  .then on the get params  i can make  this const api1_secretkey = parameterList.Parameter[1].Value after promise resolved. but since the export module is already done the other file carries undefined in the secret key even after it is changed on promise resolve.

Comment: What is your issue when using an async function?

Comment: i want the getparams to behave like async or any wrapper around it do it , updated question

Comment: "*Is there any way to make AWS SSM getparameters sync?*" - no. "*I understand that await cant be without async*" - actually, you can use top-level `await`, and it might be the sensible solution here

Comment: Is there a way to use top level await in node js without  makinf the type : module in package,json cause the project code has require() everywhere

Comment: Taking a look into mjs file extension , having trouble with import and export